# splunk alert to check every minute

Tags: cron, splunk

I'm trying to make an alert in splunk that checks every minute for query results. For testing purposes I set the interval to 361s to ensure that I get plenty of results and see if the results from one check will also still be there in the subsequent 5-6 checks.

This is what I configured: (sorry for posting german screenshot, but that is our splunk is installed)

[image]

I'm only getting an e-mail at the full hour. Considering my 361s interval, a successfull trigger are 11h00 should also result in a successfull trigger at 11h01, 11h02 etc., but there is no e-mail. And there definitely are query results every few minutes.

isn't "0 * * * *" the corret cron expression for "every minute"? And what is "Ablauf" anyways? Is this the issue maybe, I can't find any documentation what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the first digit for the cron expression is for minutes and not for seconds. I guess that explains it.

Comment: Correct. 0 * * * * means run at minute :00 of each hour. I advise against that, BTW, because too many scheduled searches try to run at that time. Use 1 * * * * or 2 * * * *, instead. The English page uses "Expires" for "Ablauf".  Results generated by the alert are discarded after this time (24 hours, in the example).